# dunst notification printing delayed

Tags: linux, shell, notifications

I want to be able to use a bash script to respond to notifications automatically.
Therefore I tried dunst with its `-print` argument in order to extract notification info from stdout.

The problem is that as soon as I pipe dunst's stdout into any other program, the notifications are "behind by one notification". So the first notification is not received until I got the next one. The second is not received until the third arrives etc.
Without any piping symbol it works perfectly. I checked if this could be some buffering problem and tried to prefix the dunst command with `unbuffer` but then dunst immediately exits for some reason.

I didn't use any configuration file because I just want debugging info from dunst itself. Therefore my command was just `dunst -print | cat` as well as `notify-send "test"` for testing purposes. As I said before just `dunst -print` works perfectly

Comment: I have found a `sleep` delay can help when this occurs with dunst eg  `sleep 0.2`